# Can't upgrade file geodatabase from 10.0 to 10.5

Tags: arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5

I want to examine / use ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 on some data that was all created in 10.0 in a file geodatabase.  However, when I try to "Upgrade Geodatabase" (either through the geoprocessing tool by right-clicking Properties -> Upgrade Geodatabase), 10.5.1 thinks that the geodatabase is "up to date" at 10.0.

[image]

I know everything's not fine because trying to manipulate the data every so often throws me this error:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: One thing you could try is simply create a new empty File GDB at the current version, then copy the dataset into the new GDB.  Also though, I don't know if the GDB being up to date or not is by any means the only thing that would throw an error message in an esri program... just saying there could be numerous other causes.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain UI messages as ASCII text, allowing legibility on all devices, and permitting free-text search for others with the same issue.  Unfortunately, you are more likely dealing with a corrupt FGDB than one which hasn't been upgraded (the format hasn't changed since 10.0, which is what the first message tells you). Tech Support might be able to help, but it's more likely than not a lost cause to recover the corrupted data,

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't any customization done on this data? Or an extension was used that you don't have with 10.5.1 like ArcFM? Old KB article on the error: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002980

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the heads up on the ASCII text, this is my first SE post and I'll remember that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I had custom class extensions set up at 10.0 that I need to remove in order to upgrade the data.